# Linking your github through the aws cloud 9 text editor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

I keep getting the error message below when I try to commit my changes to GitHub. Any solution on how to get around this? I'm still a novice when understanding how to push changes I've made to github from the new code I've added.

> fatal: 'changes' does not appear to be a git repository
>
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights
> and the repository exists.

Answer (score 0):

Git is trying to push to the repository named `changes`. But returns a failed response either because the remote name doesn't exist or the path given is wrong. Here, the remote name doesn't even exist (*that's the meaning of this error*).

```
[ ] Check your `git remote -v` to see if a remote named `changes` exist 
[ ] Configure `changes` as a remote address
```

---

First, check what you've configured `remote` to be

```
$ git remote -v
origin git@github.com:ashwink823/project.git (fetch)
origin git@github.com:ashwink823/project.git (push)
```

In the above example `origin` is the name of the remote we've configured git to fetch from or push to. If I try to push to a remote named `changes` it will return a fatal error because we haven't configured `changes` to be a remote address.

```
$ git push changes
fatal: 'changes' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

But if I add `changes` like

```
$ git remote add changes git@githubcom:clmno/project.git

# now, this will work
$ git push changes
```

Comment: So after it says origin  changes (fetch)
origin  changes (push)
update  https://github.com/ashwink823/personalwebsite (fetch)
update  https://github.com/ashwink823/personalwebsite (push) what would the next steps be?

Comment: @ashwin.k823 Now that you've set `update` as the remote that points to the github repository. To pull you can `git pull update <branch name>` and to push you can  `git push update <branch name>`.